# How do I format the colors and fonts in a VBA textbox in ppt

Tags: vba, textbox, powerpoint

I've created a macro in ppt to insert a text box with next year's date, since the built-in insert date is only for the current year:

```
Sub displaynextyear()

present = Year(Date)

ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes.AddShape _
(Type:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=500, Top:=150, Width:=100, Height:=25) _
.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "{" & present + 1 & "}"

End Sub
```

It works, but I want to fine-tune it so it matches the slide's background color, font size, etc. Every time I try to insert likely formatting parameters, I get error messages.
How do I customize, please? And how would I get it to run automatically whenever the ppt presentation is opened?

Thanks!
John

Comment: PowerPoint won't run code automatically when a presentation opens. There's a relatively simple workaround if you want to execute code when a slide show starts; if you want to run code when a presentation opens, it can be done, but only if you have written and installed an add-in to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

The `.Background` method makes a shapes background match that of its slide.

```
Sub displaynextyear()
    Dim shp As Shape

    present = Year(Date)

    Set shp = ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes.AddShape _
    (Type:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=500, Top:=150, Width:=100, Height:=25)
    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "{" & present + 1 & "}"

    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 20
    shp.Fill.Background     'match the slide background

End Sub
```

This works in PowerPoint 2010, so most likely in PPt 2007 as well.

Note: We cannot record macros in PPt 2010 to help find methods/properties.